# Diagonal elements Array

Tags: java, arrays, random

How I can generate a diagonal array:
first element `arr[0][0]` is random <4;10>, next diagonal elements are random but higher than previous element but not higher than 10,

example:

8  0  0  0

0 10  0  0

0  0 13  0

0  0  0 17

```
    int lengthArray = scan.nextInt();
    int[][] array = new int[lengthArray][lengthArray];
    array[0][0] = rnd.nextInt(7) + 4;
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
// generate number diagonal
            array[i][i] = rnd.nextInt(
                    (((array[i - 1][i - 1] + 10) - (array[i - 1][i - 1] + 1) + 1)) + (array[i - 1][i - 1] + 1));
        }
    }
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You claim they cannot be higher than 10, but in your example you show values higher than 10. Do you mean the *difference* cannot be higher than 10?

Comment: Make your question clear. Your example and Questions are totally complementary

Comment: Whats that second for-loop doing? You're never using `j`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but `(((array[i - 1][i - 1] + 10) - (array[i - 1][i - 1] + 1) + 1)) + (array[i - 1][i - 1] + 1));` = `array[i - 1][i - 1]  + 13` parenthesis are useless with `+ -`

Comment: array[0][0] = 8;  array[1][1] = <9;18> (example 17); array[2][2] = <18;27> ...

Comment: First make a correction to your question and come back. And as Dennis Koch mentioned j in the second loop is never used what are you trying to achieve with inner loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add are random value between 0 and 10 (exclude) to the value of the previous one. That will give a range of `previous -> previous + 9`

```
array[i][i] = rnd.nextInt(10) + (array[i - 1][i - 1]);
```

Here is the full code to test :

```
int lengthArray = 5;
int[][] array = new int[lengthArray][lengthArray];
Random rnd = new Random();
array[0][0] = rnd.nextInt(7) + 4;
for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i][i] = rnd.nextInt(10) + (array[i - 1][i - 1]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
}
```

One output :

```
[4, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 6, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 8, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 15, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 19]
```